# Executing a synchornous method, but with a timeout, using System.Reactive

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, reactive-programming, system.reactive

What's the correct way to call the `Read` method with a timeout?

```
public int Method()
{
       return Read();
}
```

I've tried with this, but my application is shutting down completely when a timeout happens, so I guess there's something wrong with it.

```
public int Method() 
{
     return Observable.Start(() => Read()).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Wait();
}
```

Comment: On timeout, `Titmeout` throws a `TimeoutException` that `Wait()` will propagate. Is that not what's happening? --- Ah wait. I may have misunderstood the question. Are you asking if this is the recommended way of doing that while using Rx ?

Comment: `catch (OperationCanceledException exception)`

Comment: Also `.Wait` is a bad idea, you could get deadlocks. Instead use `await`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using `Timeout` as it does control by exception, which we know is bad.

I tend to use this pattern:

```
Observable
    .Amb(
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)).Select(x => (int?)null),
        Observable.Start(() => (int?)Read()))
```

`Amb` fires on the first observable to produce a value and then ignores the other. Just set an appropriate return value and in your case it's `int?` to allow the number to come through or a `null` if it times out.

I then use the fact that we can await the last value of an observable and I do this:

```
public async Task<int?> Method() =>
    await
        Observable
            .Amb(
                Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)).Select(x => (int?)null),
                Observable.Start(() => (int?)Read()))
            .LastAsync();
```

If you don't want to use tasks then you can still use `Wait()`:

```
public int? Method() =>
    Observable
        .Amb(
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)).Select(x => (int?)null),
            Observable.Start(() => (int?)Read()))
        .Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've posted, the `Wait` method is blocking until the `Observable` completes or an exception is thrown. In case of a timeout, the `Timeout` operator will throw a `TimeoutException`. As `Wait` doesn't handle exceptions, it propagates this exception, causing the application to crash.

You could use `Subscribe` instead of `Wait` and handle the exception:

```
public int Method()
{
    int result = 0;
    var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    Observable
        .Start(() => Read())
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        .Subscribe(
            x => { result = x; resetEvent.Set(); },  // onNext
            ex => { /* handle exception */ resetEvent.Set(); }  // onError
        );

    resetEvent.WaitOne();  // Wait until the Observable completes or an exception is thrown
    return result;
}
```

This code starts an `Observable` that wraps the `Read` method. It will either complete with a result (which is assigned to `result`) or fail with a `TimeoutException`. In either case, the `AutoResetEvent` is signaled, allowing the `WaitOne` method to complete and the `Method` method to return the result.

Make sure to replace `/* handle exception */` with your own exception handling code. For example, you could set `result` to a special value that indicates a timeout, or you could log the exception.

One last thing: `Method` is still blocking because of `resetEvent.WaitOne()`. This might be okay for a console application, but in a GUI application, this would freeze the UI until the `Read` method completes or the timeout occurs. If you want to avoid blocking, you'll need to use a different design, for example by making `Method` asynchronous or by providing a callback that is invoked when the `Read` method completes.